# getting the number of records having a specific condition and the the other that don't for the same card in the same query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table for which multiple child records can be linked in the following way:

```
 table object:

 id    description   type
```

where id is a primary key.

I have another table, events that has as foreign key the object id

```
table event

id  object_id status  description
```

the status field can have a value 0 or 1 indicating if it's pending or not

I need to get in one query all objects and the number of events pending and the number of events that are not

For example:

```
Object record:

id    description    type
---- ------------- ------
1    Printer        hardware
```

Related event records

```
Event records

id   object_id     status    description
---- ---------    --------   --------------
1    1            0           Ordered
2    1            0           Shipped
3    1            1           Received by customer
```

The expected result is

```
  object_id    pending_events      completed_events
  ----------- -----------------   -----------------
  1            1                  2
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Show your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select  e.object_id,
        sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pending_events,
        sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as completed_events
from events e
group by e.object_id;
```

If status only takes on the values of 0 and 1, you can actually simplify this to:

```
select  e.object_id,
        sum(status) as pending_events,
        sum(1-status) as completed_events
from events e
group by e.object_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COUNT` for this. If the `COUNT` parameter is null it won't count the row; if the parameter is non-null it will.

```
SELECT
  object_id,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS pending_events,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS completed_events
FROM Event
GROUP BY object_id
```

Note that the `THEN 1` is just specifying a non-null value; it could be `THEN 'a'` or `THEN 'apples'` or `THEN 'oranges'`. The key point is non-null values are counted; null values are not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  O.ID AS OBJECT_ID
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN E.STATUS = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PENDING_EVENTS
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN E.STATUS = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COMPLETED_EVENTS
FROM    OBJECT O    
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        EVENT E
ON      O.UD = E.OBJECT_ID
GROUP BY
        O.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select object_id,
       sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pending_events,
       sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as completed_events
from [Event Records]
group by object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/350a3/5)

```
SELECT
  obj_id,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS pending_events,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS completed_events
FROM Event
GROUP BY obj_id
```